# Какую базу данных использовать для приложения на javascript

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Если я пишу приложения типа todo, куда я буду вводить список дел, можно их сохранять в localStorage. А как сделать чтобы можно было сохранять все в отдельную базу данных на своем компьютере? Какая база данных для это подходит лучше?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ради разнообразия, если курите SQL, попробуйте https://duckdb.org/.
А нет, так `indexedDB`.

Comment: ....Любая база.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что вы, что вы. Толька та база, что данных...))

Comment: @Leonid хех :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую начать с MySQL, а так - подойдёт любая СУБД. Имейте в виду, что для этого нужно будет разработать серверную часть, которая будет взаимодействовать с БД. Если речь идёт о JavaScript-e смотрите в сторону Node.js.

Comment: Я начинаю практиковаться, и планирую сделать что-то вроде дневника, куда буду вносить какие нибудь события. Например, "30.10.2021 купил ноутбук". А потом, если надо будет вспомнить, ввел в поле поиска "ноутбук", а приложение связалось с базой и вытащила для меня эту заметку.
**Судя по вашему ответу, не получится чтобы js приложение само сделало запрос к базе, как в localStorage, я имею ввиду на стороне клиента, обязательно нужно бэкенд настраивать и в node.js писать?**

Comment: @Александр, ваше утверждение неверно [duckdb](https://shell.duckdb.org/) прекрасно работает прямо в браузере без каких либо серверов. Совместно , например, с [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) можно сделать кросс-платформенное приложение для любых десктоп и мобильных платформ.